# Django: How to return all models associated with a ForeignKey including all attributes of those models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have an app that I want to simply display all the URL links a page has associated with it when that page is visited.

It's similar to reddit in that there are many userpages (aka subreddits) and each page has an infinite possible amount of submitted links associated with it. The `newlinkposts` records are associated with a certain page via a `ForeignKey`.

Given a page, wow can I get all the related `newlinkpost` objects (including their corresponding likes, link comment, and post date) returned, in order to display them in a template?

My `newlinkpost` object is defined as follows:

```
class newlinkpost(models.Model):
     newlink_tag = models.ForeignKey('userpagename') #tags link to which userpage it belongs to
     link_comment = models.CharField(max_length=128) #comment to go along with post
     post_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False, null=False) #submission     datestamp. later make it track editable posts if edit function is implemented
     url = models.URLField(max_length = 1024, null=False) #actual submitted link
     link_likes = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=0) #need to later create like button which will +1 the value

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.url
```

Comment: By the way... not really related to your question, but by convention classes (including model subclasses) are usually named with uppercase letters so that they are obviously distinguished from instances. e.g. ``NewLinkPost`` and ``UserPageName`` in your case.

Comment: Thanks letting me know. I'll go through and change the model classes to uppercase letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a `ForeignKey` within a model, as well as creating an attribute in the source model (in your case, `newlinkpost`) allowing you to find the one associated object, Django also creates a corresponding attribute inside the *target* model (in your case apparently `userpagename`).

By default this attribute is named after the source table, so in your case it will be `newlinkpost_set`.

That allows you to ask the question you're looking to answer: which `newlinkpost` objects have this `userpagename`?:

```
all_links = userpagename_instance.newlinkpost_set.all()
```

If you wish to apply additional filters, you can use the `filter` method instead:

```
some_links = userpagename_instance.newlinkpost_set.filter(...)
```

The `newlinkpost_set` attribute contains a [RelatedManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/) object, which is a subtype of [Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Manager), allowing you to use the same set of methods you could use on `newlinkpost.objects`, along with some additional methods allowing you to create new related objects.

---

Here's an example view using this technique: (this assumes you've got the model classes imported into the views module):

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def user_page(request, user_id):
    page = userpagename.get(pk=user_id)
    links = page.newlinkpost_set.all()
    return render(
        request,
        "myapp/user_page.html",
        {
            page: page,
            links: links,
        }
    )
```

...and here's an example of using that "links" variable in the template:

```
<ul>
{% for link in links %}
    <li><a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.link_comment }} - {{ link.link_likes }} likes</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: When I try the command in the python shell after importing the models, I get "userpagename_instance" is not defined error. Do I have to import any other code to make the "_instance" and "_set" suffixes not return an error? Also, what exactly does the userpage_instance command fetch? Thanks for your help.

Comment: ``userpagename_instance`` was intended to represent a ``userpagename`` object you've already loaded, e.g. using ``userpagename_instance = userpagename.get(pk=1)`` to load the page whose id is ``1``, or however else you're loading your ``userpagename`` objects.

Comment: If you update your question to include an example of the view code for your user pages then I could try to write a more complete example in my answer, showing how it works with the code you already have.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it worked perfectly after your clarification. So now I've got a queryset loaded that is all the posts of that related page (by post I mean the URLField) which is excellent. Is there a way I can also get the associated likes and link comment for each of those posts? As it is now, I have a queryset for each userpagename which is great because that's all I need after getting the link likes and link comment for each one in the queryset.

Comment: I added a more complete example to my answer, showing a view that creates the query set and passes it into the template. Does that answer your remaining questions?

Comment: This worked great. I really appreciate your help. Now when I visit the selected usernamepage I get a list of links and their corresponding likes which is exactly what I wanted. I also used the order_by('-post_date') function to order the submissions so the latest submissions show up at the top of the page. I have one question, if I wanted to also have the datefield displayed before the number of likes after the urlfield and comment field, do I add {{ link.post_date }} to the template? When I do that, I get "None" displayed there when I view the page through the test server. Thanks again.

Comment: ``{{ link.post_date }}`` looks fine to me. Are you sure you have that field populated in the database? Could it be that all of your links actually do have a null post date?

Comment: It worked now. I had to delete the db file and resync the database and start over. It was probably as you said due to a null post date. I removed the null field. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: It sounds like you've got the answer you needed, in which case please consider marking this answer as accepted. (click the check mark to the top left of the answer) This will stop the question showing on the site as "Unanswered".

Answer (score 0):

You just use the reverse relationship.

```
my_userpagename.newlinkpost_set.all()
```

Comment: I haven't used these commands yet in my project so I'm having a bit of an issue getting them to not return errors "my_userpagename is not defined"/"newlinkpost_set is not defined". When I append the suffix "_set" or prefix "my_" I get these errors but normal calls such as newlinkpost.objects.all() returns everything fine without error. Thanks for your input.